# Defining onComplete function on uploadify, after running it

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Is there a way to define a different (or even better, an *additional*) onComplete function to an already setup uploadify element?

I thought I could use [uploadifySettings](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/methods/uploadifysettings/), but that didn't seem to work.

The idea is something like this:

```
$('#file1').uploadify({
  //normal uploadify options
});

//some more code ...

$('#file1').uploadifySettings('onComplete', function( ... ) { ... } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I took a look at the source code of uploadify (always a good idea, apparently), and this works :)

```
 $('#file1').bind('uploadifyComplete', function( ... ) { ... });
```